# Many-to-many with Same Id Key fields

Tags: nhibernate, orm

How do I join two tables as many-to-one and one-to-many in nHibernate. They both have the same 'PLAN_ID' as the key column. My Database structures pre-existing.

Below is the mapping I am using and the error I'm getting:

Table: **PLANN** (**one**)

```
PLAN_ID  <-- PRIMARY KEY
START_DATE
CHECK_CHAR
...
```

Table: **PLANN_DOCUMENT** (**to many**)

```
PLAN_ID <-- PRIMARY KEY
DOC_ID <-- ID to a DOCUMENT table
DOC_NAME
DOC_TYPE
```

**Plann class:**

```
public virtual... PlanId, StartDate, CheckChar, PlanStatus,
public virtual ISet<DocsysHoldingDoc> DocsysHoldingDocs { get; set; }
public virtual DocsysHoldingDoc DocsysHoldingDoc { get; set; }
```

**PlannDocument Class:**

```
public virtual...PlanId, DocId, DocName, DocType
public virtual Plann PlannItem { get; set; }
```

**Plann HBM XML**

```
<class name="Plann" abstract="true" table="PLANN">
    <id name="PlanId" column="PLAN_ID"
        <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>
    <property name="StartDate" column="START_DATE" /> 
    <property name="CHECK_CHAR" column="CHECK_CHAR" /> 
    ...

    <set name="PlannDocument" table="PLANN_DOCUMNET">
        <key column="PLAN_ID"></key> //<<KEY IN JOINING TABLE BUT ALSO ID IN THIS TABLE
        <one-to-many class="DocsysHoldingDoc"/>
     </set>
</class>
```

**PlannDocument HBM XML**

```
<class name="PlannDocument" abstract="true" table="PLANN_DOCUMNET">
    <id name="PlanId" column="PLAN_ID"  type = "int">
        <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>
    <property name="DocId" column="DOC_ID" />
    <property name="DocName" column="DOC_NAME" />
    <property name="DocType" column="DOC_TYPE" />

    <many-to-one name="Plann" column="PLAN_ID"></many-to-one>

</class>
```

> ERROR:
>   NHibernate.MappingException: 'Unable to build the insert statement for class <>.PlannDocument: a failure occurred when adding the Id of the class'
>
> ArgumentException: **The column 'PLAN_ID' has already been added in this SQL builder** Parameter name: columnName

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments (under deleted answer), name of primary key column in both the tables is same - i.e. `PLAN_ID`. You want to join these two tables based on many-to-one relation.

The problem here is that the same column name (from two different tables) is being added twice in the mapping.

That is why the error:

> ERROR: NHibernate.MappingException: 'Unable to build the insert statement for class <>.**PlannDocument**: a failure occured when adding the Id of the class'
>
> ArgumentException: The column **'PLAN_ID'** has already been added in this SQL builder Parameter name: columnName

In PlannDocument HBM, column name `PLAN_ID` is first used while creating `id` as below:

```
<id name="PlanId" column="PLAN_ID"  type = "int">
```

and then, again while creating `many-to-one` relation as below:

```
<many-to-one name="Plann" column="PLAN_ID"></many-to-one>
```

This is causing conflict of column name.

The solution I can think is to change the column name to something defer from the other table. Also, modify the classes and mappings accordingly.

I understand that this cannot be the solution every time and in all the conditions.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the same column for `identifier` and for your desired `many-to-one` association - it's not really a `many-to-one` association. Sharing the same `identifier` means it's `one-to-one` association. Just use it instead of your `many-to-one` mapping in PlannDocument.hbm.xml and it should work:

```
<one-to-one name="Plann" constrained="true" />
```

If your `PlannDocument.Plann` can be null than use `constrained="false"` instead. But be aware that this will cost you additional query to check if `Plann` really exists.

Comment: Good point but the question clearly says one `PLANN` may have many `PLANN_DOCUMNET`s.