# NHibernate Exception while building SessionFactory if column name is same for association property

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I have Master and Detail tables. Name of Primary Key column in both the tables is same: `Id`.
While building session factory, I am getting following exception:

```
NHibernate.MappingException: Unable to build the insert statement for class ........Detail1Entity: a failure occured when adding the Id of the class ---> System.ArgumentException: The column 'Id' has already been added in this SQL builder
Parameter name: columnName
   at NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlInsertBuilder.AddColumnWithValueOrType(String columnName, Object valueOrType)
   at NHibernate.SqlCommand.SqlInsertBuilder.AddColumns(String[] columnNames, Boolean[] insertable, IType propertyType)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.GenerateInsertString(Boolean identityInsert, Boolean[] includeProperty, Int32 j)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.GenerateInsertString(Boolean identityInsert, Boolean[] includeProperty, Int32 j)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.GenerateInsertString(Boolean[] includeProperty, Int32 j)
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.AbstractEntityPersister.PostInstantiate()
   at NHibernate.Persister.Entity.SingleTableEntityPersister.PostInstantiate()
   at NHibernate.Impl.SessionFactoryImpl..ctor(Configuration cfg, IMapping mapping, Settings settings, EventListeners listeners)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
   at ...........
```

I have following tables:

```
CREATE Table MasterTable1
(
[Id] [INT] IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT MasterTable1PK PRIMARY KEY,
[MasterData] [VARCHAR] (100)
)

CREATE Table DetailTable1
(
[Id] [INT] IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DetailTable1PK PRIMARY KEY,
[MasterId] [INT] NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DetailTable1_MasterTable1_FK FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES MasterTable(MasterId),
[DetailData] [VARCHAR] (100)
)
```

Following are entity definitions:

```
public class Master1Entity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string MasterData { get; set; }
}

public class Detail1Entity
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string DetailData { get; set; }

    public virtual Master1Entity Master1 { get; set; }
}
```

Following are the mappings:

```
internal class Master1Map : ClassMapping<Master1Entity>
{
    public Master1Map()
    {
        Table("MasterTable1");

        Id(x => x.Id, im =>
        {
            im.Column("Id");
            im.Generator(Generators.Identity);
        });
        Property(x => x.MasterData);
    }
}

internal class Detail1Map : ClassMapping<Detail1Entity>
{
    public Detail1Map()
    {
        Table("DetailTable1");

        Id(x => x.Id, im =>
        {
            im.Column("Id");
            im.Generator(Generators.Identity);
        });
        Property(x => x.DetailData);

        ManyToOne(x => x.Master1, map => { map.Column("Id"); });
    }
}
```

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55181707/5779732), I know that if I rename `[MasterTable1].[Id]` to `[MasterTable1].[MasterId]` and modify the entities and mappings accordingly, this will work well.

But, I cannot change the underlying database; this is legacy database I have to take on.

Also, this is Many-to-One relationship. One Master will have multiple Detail entries.

Is there any way to make this work without changing column name in database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't confuse collection mapping (expects column from association table) with entity mapping (expects column from owner table).  `ManyToOne` is entity mapping and it expects column from **owner** table. In your case owner table for `Master1` is `DetailTable1` and column you need to map is `MasterId`:

```
internal class Detail1Map : ClassMapping<Detail1Entity>
{
...
 ManyToOne(x => x.Master1, map => { map.Column("MasterId"); });
```